# Create empty directory using Scons

Tags: scons

I am trying to add new empty folder into existing project. In `SConscript.3dn` file I use:

```
Import('env_rcp')
e = env_rcp.Clone()
# another code ...
e.Execute(e.Mkdir('$RUNTIMEDIR/resources'))
```

and while building locally I get `AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'Mkdir'`

I did try also `os.Mkdir('$RUNTIMEDIR/resources')`, then I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mkdir'`.

Some import is missing, or should I define `Mkdir` somehow? In Scons [manual](https://scons.org/doc/1.3.0/HTML/scons-user/x3015.html) I did not find much help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is: `e.Execute(Mkdir('$RUNTIMEDIR/resources'))`